# How to pass shortcuts from MainWindow to the UserControl in ContentControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, keyboard-shortcuts

The UserControl dynamically loaded to the ContentControl in my Window does not receive keyboard shortcuts defined inside of UserControl XAML, in case it is not focused.

I need to implement keyboard shortcuts for dynamically loaded UserControl, without focusing the UserControl.

I cannot define InputBindings on MainWindow, because the InputBindigs are changing depends on currently loaded UserControl.

1) So I tried to send all Window_KeyUp to the loaded UserControl via RaiseEvent, no luck. (StackOverflow Exception or no action called)

2) I tried also fillup the MainWindow.InputBindings by LoadedUserControl.InputBindings when the UserControl has been loaded to the ContentControl... no luck (defined command is unknown in context)

```
UserControl.xaml
----------------

<UserControl.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="N" Command="{Binding Path=NewOrderCommand}" Modifiers="Control" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

This is working if UserControl is focused.

So to get rid of focusing I tried this:

```
MainWindow.xaml.cs
-------------------

private void MainWindow_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // ModulePanel points to the loaded UserControl
    ViewModel.CurrentModule.ModulePanel.RaiseEvent(e);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

So this issued StackOverflowException

I tried set e.Handled = true; before RaiseEvent(e) but it does not pass the event to the UserControl - so nothing happens;

I also tried to get InputBindings from UserControl to MainWindow:

```
foreach(InputBinding bi in UserControl.InputBindings)
   MainWindow.InputBindings.Add(bi);
```

But I got exception in Debug window:

Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=NewOrderCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'KeyBinding' (HashCode=35527846); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

My expectation is, that I will dynamically change Window InputBindings depends on loaded UserControl, where the InputBindings are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `UserControl` to be able to handle all key presses in the window, you could get a reference to the parent window using the `Window.GetWindow` once the `UserControl` has been loaded and then hook up an event handler to it:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
            parentWindow.PreviewKeyDown += ParentWindow_PreviewKeyDown;
        };
        Unloaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
            parentWindow.PreviewKeyDown -= ParentWindow_PreviewKeyDown;

        };
    }

    private void ParentWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good workaround. Thanks for little kick. Still I would like to rather use KeyInput defined in XAML than switch / case in each UserControl.

Comment: But you can't use `KeyBinding` defined in XAML to accomplish this. And you can put the common code in a base class or extension method or whatever where all `UserControls` can access it.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution I can use for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ViewModels as DataContext and let them communicate with each other using a Messenger. You can send the Information needed to the ViewModel of the unfocused Usercontrol.

If you want to stick with code-behind, subscribe to the eventhandler on Mainwindow:

```
PreviewKeyUp += userCtrl.OnKeyUp;
```

and handle it in your UserControl

```
public void OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MyTextBlock.Text = e.Key.ToString();
    }
```